# MPMoviePlayerViewController controls layout is breaked

Tags: ios, video, video-player

I'm using this code to play local video, but control layout is broken:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"simulation" ofType:@"mp4"]];

MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerViewController];
```

[image]